# DynamoDB queries return no items within Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Basically, I have a DynamoDB connection within a Lambda function. Will post code below. This DynamoDB connection *seems* to be behaving properly - it's able to call the listTable and describeTable functions successfully, which means it's got the right configuration - but querying it returns nothing, even on queries I know are correct and have tested on the Dynamo console.

UPDATE: Was able to successfully query with a string on a separate index, but still unable to query based on a binary...

Here's a part of the Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const SNS = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31', region: 'sa-east-1' });
const DDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10', region: 'sa-east-1' })
const Lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ apiVersion: '2015-03-31' });

const async = require('async');

const CREATE_NOTIFICATIONS = 'create-notifications'
const QUERY_TOKENS = 'query-tokens'

function getUsers(functionName, message, callback) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(message);
    var users = [];
    console.log(DDB);
    async.forEachOf(msg.targetsb64, function(value, index, cb) {
        console.log("getUsers b64: ", value)
        console.log(typeof(value))
        DDB.describeTable({
            TableName: 'tsGroups'
        }, function(err, data) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(data.Table.KeySchema)
        })
        DDB.query({
            TableName: 'tsGroups',
            KeyConditionExpression: "identifier = :v_user",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":v_user": {"B": value}
            }
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err)
            } else {
                console.log("data: ", data)
                console.log("items: ", data.Items)
                data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
                    users.push.apply(users, item.users.BS)
                })
                cb()
            }
        })
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err)
        } else {
            console.log("getUsers users: ", users);
            const promises = users.map((user) => invokeQueryTokens(functionName, msg, user));
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                const result = `Users messaged: ${users.length}`;
                console.log(result);
                callback(null, result);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

I've tried using KeyConditions instead of KeyConditionExpression, to no avail. Value refers to a base64 identifier string that's passed along from an earlier Lambda function - I've tried hard-coding the correct value, doesn't help. The describeTable function is only there to detail that DynamoDB is connecting properly, and in the correct region.

TL;DR: The data.Items value in the above code snippet is always an empty array, even when doing a query I know should return something. What's my error here?

Thanks, and cheers!